# Seleccionar valor por id

Tags: python, django

les tengo una pregunta, en mi view.py tengo una consulta

ejemplo

```
ing =ingresos.objects.values('id').annotate(Sum('precio'))
```

funciona bien pero como vereis en el tamplete me "pinta" todos los valores de la base de datos, como podria hacer esa consulta para solo mostrar el annotate (valor) segun el id del establecimiento

url.py

```
url(r'^detalle_establecimiento/(?P<id_establecimiento>\d+)$','principal.views.detalle_establecimiento'),
```

se que la culsulta que hago me devuelbe el valor correcto pues se lo hago a todos los objetos de un modelo, pero quiero seleccionar el valor que le corresponde a cada establecimiento, o sea id

Comment: Agrega un filtro con el valor de `id_establecimiento`.

Comment: @toledano importando F() o en el mismo template?

Comment: En `ing` de tu vista... puedes usar un método `F()` pero no creo que sea necesario.

Comment: queda asi  ` ing =ingresos.objects.filter(pk=id_establecimiento).values('id').annotate(Sum('establecimiento'))`

Comment: @toledano todo bien pero cuando llamo a la variable en en el template `{{ing}}` me devuelbe los valores doblemas, solo necesito el valor, este es el resultado 
$ [{'natural__sum': 1253.0, 'natural': 1253.0}]

Comment: Lo que devuelve es correcto, no? Es lo que estás pidiendo. Pides el campo `id` y suma de `precio`. Si no te devuelve eso, tal vez estés redefiniendo tu variable `ing`. Imposible saberlo ya que no incluyes un __[mcve]__.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58067/discussion-between-roly-miranda-diaz-and-toledano).

Comment: lo que necesito es limpiar el resultado... mostrar solo el valor

Comment: `ing = ingresos.objects.values('precio').annotate(precio=Sum('precio'))`. Luego el precio lo tendrás en `ing[n]['precio']`

Answer (score 0):

Si estas partiendo de un DataFrame lo mas simple es aplicar un agrupamiento y al final la función de suma:

`ing.groupby('ID').sum()`